# Homomorphisms from BV

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Denote by $\mathsf{BV}(\mathbb T)$ the Banach space of functions on the circle with bounded variation which is a Banach algebra under the pointwise product. Is there a surjective homomorphism from $\mathsf{BV}(\mathbb T)$ onto $\ell_1(\mathbb Z)$ (with convolution)?

My motivation comes from the fact that Fourier coefficients of functions in $\mathsf{BV}(\mathbb T)$ vanish at infinity however I am not sure if this is directedly related.

Comment: Ask Michal Wojciechowski.

Comment: Do you require the homomorphism to respect the symmetry of the circle in any way? (viewing $\ell_1({\bf Z})$ as ${\rm A}({\bf T})$)?

Comment: I am curious if there exists any homomorphism but a more symmetric one would be better

Comment: Do you want your homomorphism to be linear?

Comment: Regarding your last comment, the Fourier transform of a function of bounded variation need not be an element in $\ell^1$. For instance the sawtooth function, or any other function whose distributional derivative has single $\delta$, has a Fourier series that decays like $|a_k| \sim k^{-1}$

Comment: @Adrian, yes but maybe BV quotients onto some subalgebra that has such property? Homs of Banach algebras are linear and multiplicative.

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question? I think the answer is no, because such a homomorphism would induce an injective continuous function from the max. ideal space of $A({\bf T})$ (which is ${\bf T}$) into the max. ideal space of ${\sf BV}({\bf T})$. I don't know immediately what the latter space is, but some looking online suggests it will be totally disconnected